# Is it possible to use whole raw string as parameter in swagger

Tags: swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

there is a url like 
http://someservice.com/confirm?{token}

Is this any way how to describe this endpoint in terms of swagger notation

if use as query parameter then you get

```
  /confirm:
    get:
      summary: ...
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: token
        ...
```

http://someservice.com/confirm?token=value that is not OK

from other side it is not possible to use url notation in follow way:

```
  /confirm?{token}:
    get:
      summary: ...
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: token
        ...
```

due to query strings in paths are not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported, neither in OpenAPI 2.0 nor in OpenAPI 3.0. Here's the corresponding feature request:

[Support for arbitrary query strings](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1502)